# Python - Finding the average of a column given matched strings in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the the number of products in a dataframe that contain words from a `wordlist`, and then find the average price of those products. The below attempt -

```
for word in wordlist:
    total_count += dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False).sum()
    total_price += dframe[dframe['Product'].str.contains(word)]['Price']
    print(dframe[dframe['Product'].str.contains(word)]['Price'])
average_price = total_price / total_count
```

returns the `average_price` as `Series([], Name: Price, dtype: float64)` and not a float value as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need `sum` of column `Price` per condition for scalar value:

```
total_count, total_price = 0, 0
for word in wordlist:
    total_count += dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False).sum()
    total_price += dframe.loc[dframe['Product'].str.contains(word), 'Price'].sum()
average_price = total_price / total_count
```

Or chache `mask` to variable for better readibility and performance:

```
total_count, total_price = 0, 0
for word in wordlist:
    mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False)
    total_count += mask.sum()
    total_price += dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].sum()

average_price = total_price / total_count
```

Solution should be simplify with regex `word1|word2|word3` - `|` means `or`:

```
mask = dframe.Product.str.contains('|'.join(wordlist), case=False)
total_count = mask.sum()
total_price = dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].sum()

average_price = total_price / total_count
```

---

```
mask = dframe.Product.str.contains('|'.join(wordlist), case=False)
average_price = dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].mean()
```

**Sample**:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['a1','a2','a3','c1','c1','b','b2','c3','d2'],
    'Price': [1,3,5,6,3,2,3,5,2]
})
print (dframe)
   Price Product
0      1      a1
1      3      a2
2      5      a3
3      6      c1
4      3      c1
5      2       b
6      3      b2
7      5      c3
8      2      d2

wordlist = ['b','c']
mask = dframe.Product.str.contains('|'.join(wordlist), case=False)
average_price = dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].mean()
print (average_price)
3.8
```

Comment: We should add some sample data.

Comment: @harry04 both solutions posted contain mask

Comment: @AntonvBR - I test all solution and return same value, thank you.

Comment: Just tried the first one! Didn't need to try the second one! Works fine! :)

Comment: Perfect. But now that you proved your point you could remove the first solution. ohh wait OP used first one... nvm. Can keep both

Comment: `total_price += dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].sum()` throws an error `cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` on some dataframes whereas, works well on others. I've used `dframe['Price'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`, but it doesn't seem to be working for 1 or 2 dataframes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @harry04 There is priblem NaNs in Product column, need `mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False, na=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use value function in order to avoid Series.

total_count += dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False).value.sum()

total_price += dframe[dframe['Product'].str.contains(word)]['Price'].value